# re-write wishlist controller

Tags: magento-1.9, controllers

I'm trying to re-write wishlist controller using following
config code

```
<frontend>
        <routers>
            <wishlist>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Retailon_Wishlist before="Mage_Wishlist">Retailon_Wishlist
                        </Retailon_Wishlist>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </wishlist>
        </routers>
</frontend>
```

controller

```
<?php
   require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Wishlist') . DS . 'IndexController.php';
class Retailon_Wishlist_IndexController extends Mage_Wishlist_IndexController  {

  Mage::log("arg", null, 'wish.log');
    protected function _addItemToWishList()
    {
        Mage::log("arg2", null, 'wish.log');
// code snippets ...
```

But this controller is not being called though my module is enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your configurations looks okay for me. However check following things

- Make sure your module resides in `app\code\local\Retailon\Wishlist\`
- Make sure your module have an activation file at `app\etc\modules\Retailon_Wishlist.xml`
- Your controller location is `app\code\local\Retailon\Wishlist\controllers\IndexController.php`
- Check [Qaisar's answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/85839/3535). Make sure there is no space in between. Try to use this.

  ```
  <config>
      <frontend>
          <routers>
              <wishlist>
                  <args>
                      <modules>
                          <retailon_wishlist before="Mage_Wishlist">Retailon_Wishlist</retailon_wishlist>
                      </modules>
                  </args>
              </wishlist>
          </routers>
      </frontend>
  </config>
  ```
- Last but not least flush your cache.

**Some Other Useful Notes**

- `Mage::log()` usage outside of the function `_addItemToWishList()` is wrong. It wont invoke by php (php basics);
- When you try to inspect, make sure the method `_addItemToWishList()` will get called.
- Also try to use this: `Mage::log("arg2", null, 'wish.log', true);` The last parameter will forcefully log the string `arg2` in `wish.log` even if it is in production mode

---

<sup>Here I assume your module resides in `local` codepool</sup>

Answer (score 3):

maybe space issue it will be in one line

```
<Retailon_Wishlist before="Mage_Wishlist">Retailon_Wishlist</Retailon_Wishlist>
```

Comment: good point. Most probably this would be the cause.

Comment: I have delete my answer..because of after page refresh.. i have seen that the same answer already provide by you.good works

Answer (score 1):

No need to define override in config.xml.

Just use below code to override:

```
 require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Wishlist') . DS . 'IndexController.php';

class Retailon_Wishlist_IndexController extends Mage_Wishlist_IndexController  {
...
```

Comment: Sorry Satish, I didnt understand your answer. OP has  his controller defined exactly like this !

Comment: Hi Rajiv, As amit having trouble to override controller using settings in config.xml. So I suggesting to no need to do any configuration in config.xml. Just require once your desired controller file to your module controller file to override it.

Comment: Without specifying rewrite in config.xml, Magento wont going to look for his controller.

Comment: I have already did it for newsletter controller and it's working fine for me. We already specifying require_once to add core controller file in our controller file. Just you need to call parent:: method whenever needed.

Comment: @SatishSojitra,does not fulfill amitshree question.....Please read the question clearfully

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with your line

> ```
> <Retailon_Wishlist before="Mage_Wishlist">Retailon_Wishlist
>                         </Retailon_Wishlist>
> ```

It should be like this

```
<frontend>
        <routers>
            <wishlist>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Retailon_Wishlist before="Mage_Wishlist">Retailon_Wishlist</Retailon_Wishlist>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </wishlist>
        </routers>
</frontend>
```

Remember when you are putting value between xml tag it should not contain any space as magento compare this value

Answer (score 0):

Update your config file :-

```
<frontend>
        <routers>
            <wishlist>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <retailon_wishlist before="Mage_Wishlist">Retailon_Wishlist</retailon_wishlist>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </wishlist>
        </routers>
</frontend>
```

Comment: FYI, There is no problem to use `Retailon_Wishlist` inside `module` node.